# How to annotate a barplot with values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using a doublebar plot to compare the total reach of each track. since the total reach of one group is significantly larger than the second group, I decided to create another column, `total reach - log(x)`, that is just the np.log of the original `total reach`. The y axis reflects the scale for the log but I want to annotate the bars with the actual values from `total reach`.

Any idea on how to do that?

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#plot a bar graph and assign track name variable to hue
double_plot = sns.barplot(
    x='date',
    y='total reach - log(x)',
    hue='track name',
    data=dflog,
    palette=['blue','red'],
    alpha=1,
    dodge=True,
)
double_plot.set_ylim(0,dflog['total reach - log(x)'].max())

for item in double_plot.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
    

for p in double_plot.patches:
    double_plot.annotate(format(p.get_height(), '.0f'), 
                   (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()), 
                   ha = 'center', va = 'center', 
                   xytext = (0, 9), 
                   textcoords = 'offset points')
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15,7)
plt.title("Total Followers - log(x) - Fleetwood Mac's Dreams")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could take the inverse logarithm of the height to get the original numbers back. Supposing the natural logarithm is used, the inverse would be `exp`. (Or `base ** height` when the logarithm uses another base.)

Personally, I prefer to name the return value of `sns.barplot` 'ax' to emphasize that it is a matplotlib ax object for which the standard matplotlib function can be used.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dflog = pd.DataFrame()
dflog['date'] = pd.to_datetime(np.repeat(pd.date_range('20200901', freq='D', periods=20), 2))
dflog['total reach - log(x)'] = np.random.uniform(0, 17, 40)
dflog['track name'] = np.tile(['Track 1', 'Track 2'], 20)

ax = sns.barplot(
    x='date',
    y='total reach - log(x)',
    hue='track name',
    data=dflog,
    palette=['blue', 'red'],
    alpha=1,
    dodge=True)
ax.set_ylim(0, dflog['total reach - log(x)'].max() * 1.15)

for item in ax.get_xticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(format(np.exp(p.get_height()), '.0f'),
                (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                ha='center', va='center',
                xytext=(0, 9),
                textcoords='offset points')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%y-%m-%d'))
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 7)
ax.set_title("Testing")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

An alternative approach could be to everywhere use the original values (without log), and set a logscale to the y-axis: `ax.set_yscale('log')`.